# How to enable VT-x on ASUS K53SV?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, virtualization, vt-x

I'm trying to install **Intel HAXM** (Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager). However, during installation, I get an error saying that **VT-x** is not enabled.

As you can see, the image below proves the opposite:

[image: http://postimg.org/image/6kep0zi35/]

*Click on the image for a larger view.*

After some research on Google, I found some developers who said I have to go into BIOS and the Advanced tab, and then enable Intel Virtualization Technology (also known as Intel VT-x).

The problem is that I don't have this option on my BIOS menu, and I can't update the BIOS version because I'm already using the latest version.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the BIOS window? (F12 usually). This option must be there somewhere, even if not exactly at the same location you found when googling.

Comment: Have you looked in your computer manual? What does it say about the advanced BIOS menu?

Comment: I see a post that if you do this solve a problem because the app manually enable for you! Only I did was that

Comment: What manufacture?  There is one manufacture that has a bug in their BIOS/UEFI dealing with VT-X being enabled/disabled.  Update your question with precise specific details.

Comment: @Ramhound Would you mind telling us who that manufacturer is? His system builder is ASUSTeK Computer and BIOS vendor is American Megatrends. Does that help? Please, be specific about what specifics you want.

Comment: @Andre I see you have selected my answer as the solution. I'm glad you found that useful. Was your problem resolved? If so, please let us know what exactly solved the problem. I for one would like to know that. Just add a comment here or under the answer.

Comment: I don't remember which one.  It's not ASUS though.  Bit I see no mention of the manufacture by the author

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enter the BIOS settings menu, and go to the Advanced tab.

[image: a]

Make sure you have an option titled **Intel Virtualization Technology** and make sure it's enabled. If it's not enabled, select it by using up (↑) and down (↓) arrow keys, and press the plus (+) or minus (-) key to change the value to **Enabled**. Also, if you have an option titled **VT-d**, be sure to enable that as well.

> Intel® Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O (VT-d) continues
>   from the existing support for IA-32 (VT-x) and Itanium® processor
>   (VT-i) virtualization adding new support for I/O-device
>   virtualization. Intel VT-d can help end users improve security and
>   reliability of the systems and also improve performance of I/O devices
>   in virtualized environments.

*Note that IA-32 above is used as a metonym to refer to all x86 versions that support 32-bit computing. In other words, it's not saying you need to have a 32-bit processor and a 32-bit operating system. It will work with 64-bit (officially Intel EM64T), as well as 32-bit.*

- ASUS K53SV has an Intel HM55 Express based motherboard according to
  [Lapspecs](http://www.lapspecs.com/detail/asus+k53sv).
- Intel VT-x is implemented in the processor.
- Intel VT-d is implemented in the motherboard.
- Intel Core i7-2670QM has VT-x support according to [Intel ARK](http://ark.intel.com/de/products/53469/).
- Intel HM55 Express has VT-d support according to [Intel ARK](http://ark.intel.com/products/43183/intel-bd82hm55-pch).
- The option **Intel Virtualization Technology** in BIOS means the same
  thing as **VT-x**.
- Click [here](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/Apps/eManual/EManual_K53SV_K53SJ_Z103.zip) to download the manual for K53SV.
- Refer to [this article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows) on Intel Developer Zone on how to properly
  install Intel HAXM on Windows.

If you have already enabled VT-x in BIOS and you still can't install Intel HAXM, then your problem might be related to something else. Here is some food for thought.

- Operating system! Intel HAXM will only work on Windows Vista or
  better, 32 or 64 bit.
- Relate to Intel HAXM itself. In which case you will probably get
  better help in the Intel Developer Zone forums, because they have
  Intel staff there who can help you troubleshoot the problem, and also
  escalate the issue to the developers in order to resolve your issue.
- Bug or limitation in the BIOS. Check and verify that you have the
  latest BIOS version available. If you already have the latest
  version, you might want to re-flash it. If that doesn't help, you
  might want to contact ASUS and beg for a newer BIOS version or have
  them help you troubleshoot the problem. In case your laptop is no
  longer supported, well... tough luck.
- Emulator, hypervisor, SDK and OS configuration. If your target
  platform is Android, you will need to use at least API level 17
  (Android 4.2 and up). You might consider switching to a different
  accelerator and/or emulator altogether.

Comment: My purpose of install this software was to create a vm! I have read this much before! If you install oracle vm the app will enable for you!!

Comment: In QEMU? What exactly is your CPU model? Are you sure you don't have the "Intel Virtualization Technology" option in your BIOS menu? As you can see from the screenshot above, taken from the manual of K53SV, the option is there. What is your BIOS version number?

Comment: His processor supports VT-x, this is not some old exotic laptop he has, he should have the option. I have an Asus K52Je with an i3 processor and enabling "Intel Virtualization Technology" in BIOS is enough to have hardware support for VMs. The OP has an i7-2670QM, check the Intel page: http://ark.intel.com/de/products/53469/ It is exactly what "Intel Virtualization Technology" means.

Comment: @daraos OK, so the CPU does have VT-x support. So what's the problem then?

Comment: I found a post in another forum, where the user actually contacted Asus with the same problem. Looks like the chipset does not support VT-x: "Thank you very much for giving me taking the time. I also found myself in the same network answers, I contacted asus and they told me that my model (K53SV) does not support VTX. I think that this problem is associated with the mobo and not the CPU since the utility intel says that the CPU supports the VTX..." http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-1903135/virtualization-technology-bios-asus-k53sv.html#12055628

Comment: My apologies for being hasty before, I just couldn't believe Asus combined an i7 processor with a chipset that does not support VT-x.

Comment: @daraos So on your own laptop (K52Je) you can only see the option "Intel Virtualization Technology" under the Advanced tab? You don't see "VT-x" or "VT-d" there?

Comment: @daraos It looks like the K53SV ships with the [HM55 Express](http://www.lapspecs.com/detail/asus+k53sv) chipset. And according to [Intel ARK](http://ark.intel.com/products/43183/intel-bd82hm55-pch) this chipset has VT-d support.

Comment: I have the hardware support on my laptop with the "Intel Virtualization Technology" setting switched on. I have no "VT-x" or "VT-d" setting. If you edit your answer, I can undo my downvote, sorry again. We would need the OP answer the questions we asked him to determine if his MB supports it, but according to that guy on the other forum, I can imagine that it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your CPU is VT-X capable (which the screenshot shows) that doesn't mean it is actually enabled.
Enabling has to be done via the Bios. It can not be done (AFAIK) while there is an OS running.
(Please note: In many Biosses the option is hidden in the "security" menu or in some "advanced settings" menu.)

If you Bios doesn't provide a setting for this (many laptop biosses simply don't have the option) you are out of luck. There is no other way to enable it.

Comment: There are ways of modding the BIOS.

Comment: @kinokijuf I know, but they are usually not within reach of the average computer-user. Not even in reach for most enthusiasts either.